# In MS Access, my report filter is not working from a list box

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a Form which contains an input for an article. Then I have another Form in the Form which contains a query for SQL. So the problem is, there are sometimes multiple locations for 1 articlenumber.

I made a listbox, to choose which location you want. I read online I have to filter in VBA the Data to get results. So I made a code to filter, no errors and the code goes down to the end(checked with msgbox).

Tried to make another list box with only the location on it. Made filter for query and report.

Comment: it would have been nice if this was a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you want to set up a form for searching through articles (data) that uses *Cascading Listboxes* to filter the articles.  The strength of this approach is also its weakness.  Database users have direct access to the returned data to make changes but then there is no explicit protection against entering bad data at this point.  (Data Validation should be added to either the table or the form)
For example, below I set up two listboxes.  The rowsource of the first listbox is Articles and in the click event of lstArticles I set the corresponding rowsource of lstLocations.

At first all articles are shown and lstLocations is not visible while it's recordsource does not look good.
[image]

For the example, I added a language attribute to each articlelocation.
[image]

after a location is picked only the appropriate article is shown
[image]

```
'sql

Option Compare Database
Dim selectedArticleID, selectedLocationID As Long

Private Sub lstArticles_AfterUpdate()
'cascading listboxs
selectedArticleID = Nz(Me.lstArticles.Column(0), 0)
selectedLocationID = 0
Me.lstLocations.RowSource = "SELECT Locations.LocationID, Locations.Location " & _
"FROM Locations INNER JOIN ArticlesLocations ON Locations.LocationID = ArticlesLocations.LocationID " & _
"WHERE ArticleID = " & selectedArticleID
ApplyFilter
End Sub

Private Sub lstLocations_AfterUpdate()
selectedLocationID = Nz(Me.lstLocations.Column(0), 0)
ApplyFilter
End Sub

Private Sub ApplyFilter()
If (selectedArticleID = 0) Then
Me.Filter = ""
Else
If (selectedLocationID = 0) Then
Me.Filter = "ArticleID = " & selectedArticleID 'the WHERE clause without the WHERE
Else
Me.Filter = "(Articles.ArticleID = " & selectedArticleID & ") And (LocationID = " & selectedLocationID & ")"
End If
End If
Me.FilterOn = True
Me.lstLocations.Visible = True
Me.lblLocation.Visible = True
End Sub
```

[image]

```
'data 'please note the many to many relationship formed by the ArticlesLocations table
+----+-----------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| ArticleID |        Title          |                    Content                             |
+----+-----------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| 1  | Introduction to AI    | AI is changing the world with its applications...     |
| 2  | Python Programming    | Python is a versatile programming language...        |
| 3  | Climate Change        | The effects of climate change are becoming evident... |
+----+-----------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+

+----+-------------+
| LocationID |  Location   |
+----+-------------+
| 1  | New York    |
| 2  | San Francisco|
| 3  | London      |
| 4  | Paris       |
+----+-------------+

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   ArticleLocationID    |     ArticleID      |     LocationID     |     LanguageVersion      |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                      1 |                  1 |                  1 | English                  |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                      2 |                  1 |                  2 | English                  |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                      3 |                  2 |                  3 | English                  |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                      4 |                  2 |                  4 | French                   |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                      5 |                  3 |                  1 | English                  |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                      6 |                  3 |                  3 | English                  |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
record source of form must include ArticleID and LocationID to be filtered so here set to: SELECT Articles.ArticleID, Locations.LocationID, Locations.Location, ArticlesLocations.LanguageVersion, Articles.Title, Articles.Content
FROM Locations INNER JOIN (Articles INNER JOIN ArticlesLocations ON Articles.ArticleID = ArticlesLocations.ArticleID) ON Locations.LocationID = ArticlesLocations.LocationID;
```

Comment: Okay I think I understand a  little bit. But why is it not working with this code in my report: 
Private Sub Detailbereich_Format(Cancel As Integer, FormatCount As Integer)
    If Me!fldArtikelnr1.Text = "" Then
        Me!TextUeberLogo1.Visible = True
    Else
        Me!TextUeberLogo1.Visible = False
    End If

    If Me!fldArtikelnr2.Text = "" Then
        Me!TextUeberLogo2.Visible = True
    Else
        Me!TextUeberLogo2.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub

Comment: I'm not sure because I don't know the structure of your report, but two things stand out in your code sample.  First, in Access reports are for printing, if you move the code to a form it may work.  When you want to pass parameters to a report you usually create a loading form from which you call Docmd.openreport with the parameters the user supplied.  Second not all events are equal.  In short, either adapt your code to run from the afterUpdate event like I show or adapt your code to run inside a button click event.